# Org export to odt incorrectly use "DEADLINE" for "SCHEDULED"

Tags: org-mode, org-export

I noticed that when org-exporting to and `odt` file, the `SCHEDULED` timestamps are changed to `DEADLINE` instead.

A minimum working org file:

```
#+TITLE: Test file
#+OPTIONS: p:t

* Section 1
** TODO Section 1.1
SCHEDULED: <2020-11-28 Sat>

Dummy texts. 
** TODO Section 1.2
DEADLINE: <2020-11-30 Mon> SCHEDULED: <2020-11-28 Sat>
Dummy texts.
```

Then I `C-c C-e`, select `export to ODT`. This is the resultant odt content:

[image]

Could this be a bug of `org`?

Versions:

- OS: Manjaro Linux
- Emacs: GNU Emacs 27.1 (build 1, x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 3.24.22, cairo version 1.17.3) of 2020-08-29
- Org: 20201123 from Archive `org`

Comment: Indeed - please report it with `M-x org-submit-bug-report`. Thanks!

Comment: I submitted a patch for this, so it should be fixed shortly. I'll add a comment when the fixed version is available.

Comment: The patch has been committed to the [stable branch](https://code.orgmode.org/bzg/org-mode/commit/546b2ba26b20acb5963f8889ca67fe4b377b555d) and has been merged to the [master branch](https://code.orgmode.org/bzg/org-mode/commit/5121209baa4e0e9532b521ec997b66bb8be31460). You should be able to get the new version of Org mode from [Org ELPA]( https://orgmode.org/elpa.html) on Monday 2020-11-30.

Comment: @NickD Thanks! Reinstalled `org` version 20201207 today, and the bug goes away.